# Trouble with stdClass::

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, distance, stdclass

I am getting this error when I execute a code for calculating the distance using the Google Maps API.

I know the error is in the `foreach { .... }` but even searching similar questions here in stackoverflow I wasn't able to come up with a solution.

---

**Error:**

```
Error: [8] Undefined property: stdClass::$distance
Webmaster has been notified.
Error: [8] Trying to get property of non-object
Webmaster has been notified.
```

**Code**

```
function distancia($origem, $destino) {
$origem = urlencode($origem);
$destino = urlencode($destino);
$data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$origem&destinations=$destino&language=pt-PT&sensor=false");
$data = json_decode($data);
$distancia = 0;

foreach ($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) {
    $distancia += $road->distance->value;
}

$distancia = $distancia / 1000; //ConversÃ£o de metros para kilometros
$distancia = round($distancia,1) . ' km';
return $distancia;
}
```

Comment: did you try var_dump($data); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it depends what data you have in `$origem` and `$destino`. If you pass for example: `Warsaw` and `Berlin` you won't get any notice or errors just `571.7 km` as result.

If you pass data that Google cannot resolve, probably `$road` is null or false so you should add extra checking inside your loop.

For example instead of:

```
$distancia += $road->distance->value;
```

it could be:

```
if ($road) {
   $distancia += $road->distance->value;
}
```